How can I access a property of a joined table from a SupabaseClient query in a map?
Giving this query:
const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("invoices")
    .select(`id, customers(name, image_url, email), amount`)
    .order("date")
    .limit(5);

I need to return data in the same format as this type:
export type LatestInvoice = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  image_url: string;
  email: string;
  amount: string;
};

I tried this way but trying to access to customers properties gives an error:

(The property does not exist in type '{name: any; image_url: any; email: any;}[]'):

const latestInvoices = data?.map(
      (invoice): LatestInvoice => ({
        id: invoice.id,
        name: invoice.customers.name,
        image_url: invoice.customers.image_url,
        email: invoice.customers.email,
        amount: formatCurrency(invoice.amount),
      })
    );

